# Samsung S8 - Keyboard Wont Stay Up - Landscape Locked App

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, landscape, samsung-s8

**Background:**

We are developing an app that requires that the login page be locked in landscape mode. The app is on the app store, and it works for all the physical/simulated phones we have tried.

**Issue:**

Here's a video that replicates the issue on a Samsung S8 RTL device.

https://youtu.be/mqCHkx9A1eY

We got notice earlier this week that a Samsung S8 user is having issues with the keyboard not staying up when he clicks in the login box. We used the Samsung Developer RTL to simulate on two of the S8's they had available.

The first device showed the issue that the customer described, but the second phone did not.

**Question:**

We are not sure if this is a common issues that developer's are seeing on the S8 or if it's our app causing the problem. Has anyone seen this issue, or have insight to this issue?

**Other Notes:**

While in the RTL we also tested on a Samsung S8+, Note 8, S7, S7 Edge and S6 to see if the problem is able to be replicated on other phones that use the Samsung Keyboard.

We also tried installing GBoard on the phone that replicated the issue, but it did not help.

**Update:**

By going in to Settings -> Display -> Full Screen Apps -> turning off my app, I get normal behavior from the keyboard.

Any insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: We too are having this problem. Did you ever figure out a way to resolve it (other than the full screen setting workaround)?

Comment: In the update section I mention that by disabling the "Full Screen Apps" setting for the app fixes the issue. We couldn't find any other work around at this time :(

Comment: We are currently developing another app with the new version of Xamarin.Forms (3.0+), who knows, maybe they fixed it.

Comment: What about making the app work with full screen mode to begin with? Adding `<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />` to android manifest.

Comment: We will give that a try and I will update the original post if it works. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Setting the `android.max_aspect` didn't seem to solve the problem all around. We are still getting reports of this on Samsung S9 devices. Please let me know if you find any other solution.

Comment: I wont have time very soon to experiment around with this. Here's a link to something that might be useful. https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive